# Can't Play Recorded Video - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

**IMPORTANT** : i can see and play this movie from iPhone Gallery Library.

i start recording here

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput;

NSString *outputFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"movie" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]];

[movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath] recordingDelegate:self];
```

After several seconds i stop recording..

```
[movieFileOutput stopRecording];
```

Then i want to play movie which i have just recorded. But i can not..MPMoviePlayer screen appear and disappear immediately..

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath]];


[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mediaPlayer];
```

**IMPORTANT** : i can see and play this movie from iPhone Gallery Library.

### ---------

---

LOGS :

outputFilePath Log :

```
2014-02-08 12:06:46.232 TestApp[3953:60b] VIDEO PATH URL : /private/var/mobile/Applications/71039166-5A6D-43BE-A47A-B20AA93D2F2A/tmp/movie.mov
```

After Disappered MPMoviePlayer log :

```
2014-02-08 12:06:47.431 TestApp[3953:60b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saving of the data is not synchronous: it's possible that the phone needs some second to finish to write the data on the output file.

Try to put the presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mediaPlayer: inside the callback [captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate/captureOutput%3adidFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL%3afromConnections%3aerror%3a) which is called when the phone finished to save the video.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath]];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mediaPlayer];
}
```